# Nuget package targeting Win10 both Win8 devices

Tags: nuget, windows-10, nuget-package, windows-10-mobile, nuget-spec

I have a generated nuget package with a library compiled for W8 and WP8.1:

.nuspec:

```
<references>
    <group targetFramework=".NETCore4.5">
        <reference file="mylib.winmd" />
    </group>
    <group targetFramework="portable-wpa81">
        <reference file="mylib.winmd" />
    </group>
</references>
```

Since I plan to target also Win10 devices (desktop and phone-arm), I am thinking about adding the libraries to the same package.
It's not quite clear if it's possible to generate a package containing these libs for w8, wp8, w10-x86 and w10-arm.

I am thinking about using the [runtimes](http://docs.nuget.org/create/uwp-create) feature added in nuget 3. How to nuspec file should modify in this case? Should a runtimes xml node be added in nuspec file?

Did some of you guys faced/solved a similar problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nuget 3+ specification definetly lacks examples.
A good example of nuget package using UWP libs is [Win2D.uwp](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Win2D.uwp/). See also [this discussion](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/1108).

The package is a simple archive.

Basically, the winmd file is in uap10.0 folder, the dlls are in runtime/win10-x86 or runtime/win10-x64 or runtime/win10-arm.

Besides this, a description file is needed in: build/native/.targets

As a summary the file structure needs to look something like:

```
build
  native
    .targets file
lib
  uap10.0
    .winmd file
runtimes
  win10-arm
    .dll file
  win10-x86
    .dll file
  win10-x64
    .dll file
  ...
```

Hope this helps others not to loose precious hours...